# what's the right size icon for toolbar on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an iPhone app which has a tool bar at the bottom of screen. In there I have a few icons. One icon that I am using on the tool bar is 84X64 pixels. The size seems to be ok on iPhone 4 and 5, but kind of small on iPhone 6 plus. So wondering what should be an appropriate size for different iPhones?

Thanks
Borna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone 6s Plus and iPhone 6 Plus (@3x):
About 66 x 66

iPhone 6s, iPhone 6, and iPhone 5 (@2x):
About 44 x 44

iPhone 4s (@2x):
About 44 x 44

iPad and iPad mini (@2x):
About 44 x 44

check out this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. so for example on iPhone 6 Plus 66 X 66 means 132 X 132 pixels?

Comment: yeah, good luck with your project :D